# Gatling - String interpolation in Scala

Tags: scala, gatling

I want to set the StringBody value in a variable:

```
exec(session => {session.set("searchBody", """{"productId":"${productID}","category":"${category}"}""")})
```

Variables `${productID}` and `${category}` exist. And I want to use the value as parameter of the function StringBody:

```
http("/products")           
  .post(appURL + "/search")
  .headers(jsonHeader)
  .body(StringBody("${searchBody}")).asJSON
```

But It doesn't work as expected. I am getting the following error:
`i.g.h.a.ResponseProcessor - Request '/products' failed:status.find.is(200), but actually found 403`

Why are not the variables printed in the string for variable `searchBody`?

**UPDATE:**

I am trying that:

```
val search= exec(repeat(products.size, "n"){
    feed(products.circular)
        .uniformRandomSwitch( //5
            exec(session => {session.set("searchBody", """{"productId":"${productID}","minPrice":"${minPrice}"}""")}),
            exec(session => {session.set("searchBody", """{"productId":"${productID}","category":"${category}"}""")})
        )
    .exec(
        http("/products")           
            .post(appURL + "/search")
            .headers(jsonHeader)
            .body(StringBody("${searchBody}")).asJSON
            .check(status.is(200), responseTimeInMillis.lessThan("${expectedResponseTime}"))
    )
})
```

I want to send different type of requests balancing uniformly and I don't want to duplicate the exec part. The endpoint is always the same and only the body is different.

Comment: HTTP 403 response code is `Forbidden` so either you are lacking some authorization or your are trying to make something you should not do. To verify if request is sent correctly you can change logging level (see: [Gatling Debugging](https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/general/debugging)) to `TRACE` this way you will get request and response printed to console. But I think that your problem is double interpolation. You are adding strings with gatling el placeholders into session and than try to read that with gatling el placeholder again, this wont work. Try to build StringBody with session expression

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of s string interpolation method of scala. Please find the below answer.

```
http("/products")           
  .post(appURL + "/search")
  .headers(jsonHeader)
  .body(StringBody(s"${searchBody}")).asJSON
```

Comment: This way he will get `${searchBody}` replaced with value of `searchBody` variable which is not set. He used it correctly as he is using gatling el string interpolation not scala one.

Comment: Is it possible to use both string interpolations together? Scala String interpolations with the `s"${variable}"` together with the one from Gatling that injects the sessions variables into the template without the `s"${variable}"` syntax?